# In Backbone.js, how can I add an attribute to the params everytime there's a POST request?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

```
model.save(), collection.create()
```

When I call these two things, the client sends a POST request with the model data to my server.  Awesome. But what if I want to add an attribute to it?

I want to add "csrf_token: 12345" to the data before it sends the POST request to my server.

How can I add that in? automatically? I want this to happen to all of my Views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option would be to use jQuery's `ajaxSetup` method to add the csrf_token to every request.

It's as easy as adding this line of code (outside of your Backbone code):

```
$.ajaxSetup({ data: { 'csrf_token' : '12345' }});
```

Since Backbone uses jQuery for all its ajax communication, the csrf_token will be included in each ajax request.

See this [blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2131-Using-jQuery-ajaxSetup-To-Accumulate-Global-Data-Parameters-For-AJAX-Requests.htm) for more information.

Comment: Is this better than yatskevich's solution?

Comment: Rails uses ajaxSetup to set the csrf_token for all the ajax requests, so I would say it is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the following will do the trick:

```
CSRFAwareModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        'csrf_token': getToken()
    }
});

MyModel = CSRFAwareModel.extend({
    ...
});
```

Comment: `collection.create()` will use `model.save()` to save your model so if your collection uses `model: CSRFAwareModel` then `csrf_token` will be included automatically.